# thread-safe file reads and writes: use a filename/lock dictionary, or just catch IOExceptions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, concurrency, ioexception

I have a few processes that periodically append lines to files, and a few that periodically read these files. These files aren't huge, and the appends are frequent but small.

I can just catch IOExceptions in a looped delay counter, or I could use a static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ReaderWriterLockSlim> to prevent contentions from happening at all.

Catching exceptions is the most straitforward, but I'm worried about eventually reading an incomplete write. Is using a lock dictionary safer, or unnecessary?

Comment: Why hack it when you just make it work correctly?  ConcurrentDictionary can't do this across processes, use a named mutex to arbitrate access.

Comment: I was thinking of using a service layer that gets between the file system and those that access it, which would allow the dictionary to work - I failed to mention the writers and readers can be on different machines. Named mutexes does get rid of the need for a dictionary, but it's not clear how I could straightforwardly allow multiple reads with it. Maybe I don't need to support that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are worried about reading an incomplete write you can always use [file.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_Open_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_) with `FileShare.None`/`Fileshare.Read`. This together with retrying should be safe, but may be slow if there is contention.

Creating a service would probably be the neatest solution. In this case I would delegate all the writing/reading to the service, cache the files if possible, and use a queue to write out changes.

Using a service just to manage locks may be dangerous if the service lost a message somewhere and a lock is not released.